# vb.net How to save File as Word & Open Office Document?

Tags: vb.net

I have a small programm and i want to save the File so i can read them later into when i open it.
How can i now save the File cause i must save 5 Variables and read them back into the Tool and if its possible i want to use the File in Word or OpenOffice too.

My Variables

```
Title - Pieces- SinglePrice- Totalprice
```

Please give me Examples for the Point in the right way.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save doc file using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811481/how-to-save-doc-file-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is store four variables from your program in a file that can also be read by Word and OpenOffice, you can do that easily enough with a text file. The following code assumes that `Title` is a String, `Pieces` is an Integer, `SinglePrice` and `TotalPrice` are Decimal.

```
Dim folder As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
Dim saveFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Save.txt")
Dim vars() As String = {Title, Pieces.ToString, SinglePrice.ToString, TotalPrice.ToString}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(saveFile, vars)
```

If you need to read the file to restore the values of the variables, you can do it like this. Note that this code assumes that the file was written by the first snippet of code, otherwise it would be necessary to validate the contaents of the file before using it.

```
Dim folder As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
Dim saveFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "Save.txt")
Dim vars() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(saveFile)
Title = vars(0)
Pieces = CInt(vars(1))
SinglePrice = CDec(vars(2))
TotalPrice = CDec(vars(3))
```