# Merging several word Docs dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I need to make a macro that would export automatically data from datagridview to a word report using a template that i created.
the program work just fine, but it generates each row in separate file for that i need all the rows in one file.

I tried to include mail merge, but i got an error "type mismatch" 
here's my code

```
            private void FindAndReplace(word.Application wordApp, string ToFindText, object replaceWithText)
                {
                    object MatchCase = true;
                    object FindText = true;
                    object MatchWholeWord = true;
                    object MatchWildcards = false;
                    object MatchSoundsLike = false;
                    object MatchAllWordForms = false;
                    object Forward = true;
                    object Format = false;
                    object MatchKashida = false;
                    object MatchDiacritics = false;
                    object MatchAlefHamza = false;
                    object MatchControl = false;
                    object Read_only = false;
                    //   object ReplaceWith = false;
                    object Visible = true;
                    object Replace = 2;
                    object Wrap = 1;
                    //wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ToFindText,replaceWithText);



                    wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ToFindText,
                        ref MatchCase,
                        ref MatchWholeWord,
                        ref MatchWildcards,
                        ref MatchSoundsLike,
                        ref MatchAllWordForms,
                        ref Forward,
                        ref Wrap,
                        ref Format,
                        ref Replace,
                        ref MatchKashida,
                        ref MatchDiacritics,
                        ref MatchAlefHamza,
                        ref MatchControl);
                    wordApp.Selection.Text = replaceWithText.ToString();

                }

                private void WordDoc(object filename, object SaveAs)
                {
                    word.Application wordApp = new word.Application();
                    object missing = Missing.Value;
                    word.Document myWordDoc = null;


                    object readOnly = false;
                    object IsVisible = false;
                    wordApp.Visible = false;





                    try
                    {

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow selectedRow in dataGridView2.Rows)
                        {
                            myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                            myWordDoc.Activate();

                            string Column1 = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                            string Column2 = selectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                            string Column3 = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                            string Column4 = selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                            string Column5 = selectedRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                            string Column6 = selectedRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                            string Column7 = selectedRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                            string Column8 = selectedRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                            string Column9 = selectedRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                            string Column10 = selectedRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
                            string Column11 = selectedRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
                            string Column12 = selectedRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
                            string Column13 = selectedRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
                            string Column14 = selectedRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
                            string Column15 = selectedRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
                            string Column16 = selectedRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
                            string Column17 = selectedRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
                            string Column18 = selectedRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
                            string Column19 = selectedRow.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
                            string Column20 = selectedRow.Cells[19].Value.ToString();
                            string Column21 = selectedRow.Cells[20].Value.ToString();

                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type1>", Column1);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type2>", Column2);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type3>", Column3);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type4>", Column4);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type5>", Column5);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type6>", Column6);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type7>", Column7);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type8>", Column8);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type9>", Column9);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type10>", Column10);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type11>", Column11);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type12>", Column12);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type13>", Column13);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type14>", Column14);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type15>", Column15);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type16>", Column16);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type17>", Column17);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type18>", Column18);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type19>", Column19);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type20>", Column20);
                            this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type21>", Column21);


                            //Saving file


                            myWordDoc.SaveAs(SaveAs.ToString() + selectedRow.ToString() + ".docx", ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
                    }

                    myWordDoc.Close();
                    wordApp.Quit();
                    MessageBox.Show("File Created!");
                }

                private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    WordDoc(filename: Getfilepath, SaveAs: Savingpath);
                }
```

I don't know what i need to change in order to get all rows's data into one file

Comment: Where do you get that error? Please have a look at [this answer and the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811537/2590375): "the fileName has to be passed by reference" if your programm is lower C# 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try creating and saving the doc file outside `foreach` clause.

```cs
myWordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
myWordDoc.Activate();

try
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow selectedRow in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        string Column1 = selectedRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        string Column2 = selectedRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        string Column3 = selectedRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        string Column4 = selectedRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        string Column5 = selectedRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        string Column6 = selectedRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        string Column7 = selectedRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        string Column8 = selectedRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        string Column9 = selectedRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        string Column10 = selectedRow.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
        string Column11 = selectedRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
        string Column12 = selectedRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
        string Column13 = selectedRow.Cells[12].Value.ToString();
        string Column14 = selectedRow.Cells[13].Value.ToString();
        string Column15 = selectedRow.Cells[14].Value.ToString();
        string Column16 = selectedRow.Cells[15].Value.ToString();
        string Column17 = selectedRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString();
        string Column18 = selectedRow.Cells[17].Value.ToString();
        string Column19 = selectedRow.Cells[18].Value.ToString();
        string Column20 = selectedRow.Cells[19].Value.ToString();
        string Column21 = selectedRow.Cells[20].Value.ToString();

        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type1>", Column1);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type2>", Column2);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type3>", Column3);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type4>", Column4);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type5>", Column5);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type6>", Column6);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type7>", Column7);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type8>", Column8);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type9>", Column9);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type10>", Column10);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type11>", Column11);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type12>", Column12);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type13>", Column13);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type14>", Column14);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type15>", Column15);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type16>", Column16);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type17>", Column17);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type18>", Column18);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type19>", Column19);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type20>", Column20);
        this.FindAndReplace(wordApp, "<Type21>", Column21);

        //Saving file
        myWordDoc.SaveAs(SaveAs.ToString() + selectedRow.ToString() + ".docx",         ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);     
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
}
```