# How to Save Console.WriteLine Output to Word File

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Looking for some help to figure out on how can I save the output of my C# program into the word file? 
Any guidance is appreciated as I am very new in this coding world.

```
class Test
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
              Application app = new word.Application();
              Document doc = app.Documents.Open(filePath);

                int p, lastInt = 0, input;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Number of Rows : ");
                input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
                {
                    for (p = 1; p <= i; p++)
                    {
                        if (lastInt == 1)
                        {
                            Console.Write("0");
                            lastInt = 0;
                        }
                        else if (lastInt == 0)
                        {
                            Console.Write("1");
                            lastInt = 1;
                        }
                    } Console.Write("\n");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

                //How to save the above Console.Writeline in the word file??

                Doc.close();
                App.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use the method `doc.SaveAs()`, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811537/5533960)

Comment: @Francisco - Would that automatically put the output in word file??

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to create a word document, create a paragraph, write text and save it.

Note that when you use `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`, that only prints the data to `Console`. You can use a helper method or something like a delegate that can do both for you. I normally use StringBuilder to keep all the data i need to save and at the end, add that to the file / document etc then save it.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    void printer(string message, bool newLine = true) 
    { 
        if (newLine) 
        {
            sb.AppendLine(message); 
            Console.WriteLine(message); 
        }
        else 
        {
            sb.Append(message); 
            Console.Write(message); 
        } 
    }

    string filePath = @"C:\temp\newdoc.doc";
    _Application word = new Application();
    var doc = word.Documents.Add();

    int p, lastInt = 0, input;
    printer("Enter the Number of Rows : ", false);
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    printer(input.ToString());
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
    {
        for (p = 1; p <= i; p++)
        {
            if (lastInt == 1)
            {
                printer("0", false);
                lastInt = 0;
            }
            else if (lastInt == 0)
            {
                printer("1", false);
                lastInt = 1;
            }
        }
        printer("\n");
    }
    printer("");

    //How to save the above Console.Writeline in the word file??
    var para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();
    para.Range.Text = sb.ToString();

    doc.SaveAs2(filePath);
    doc.Close();
```

Comment: I have Console.BackgroundColor = item.Color; too in the code....printer will not work with it....please suggest

Comment: You can add different things to the word document, formatting or what have you. This was a suggestion on how to go about it. I'll provide some formatting in update as well...

Answer (score 0):

Adding a different answer as it goes away from basics that talk about using the printer function for simply creating a StringBuilder and then append at the end.

You can see how you can change the colors and background of text the following way. Color is set when creating a new line.

```
    public static void CreateWordDocument()
    {
        //How to save the above Console.Writeline in the word file??
        string filePath = @"C:\temp\newdoc.doc";
        _Application word = new Application();
        var doc = word.Documents.Add(); 
        var para = doc.Paragraphs.Add();

        para.Range.Text = string.Empty;

        void printer(string message, WdColor color = WdColor.wdColorBlack, WdColor background = WdColor.wdColorWhite, bool newLine = true)
        {
            if (newLine)
            {
                para.Range.InsertAfter(message + Environment.NewLine);
                para.Range.Font.Color = color;
                para.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = background;
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            else
            {
                para.Range.InsertAfter(message);
                Console.Write(message);
            }
        }

        int p, lastInt = 0, input;
        printer("Enter the Number of Rows : ", WdColor.wdColorDarkTeal, newLine: false);
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        printer(input.ToString(), WdColor.wdColorGreen);

        for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
        {
            for (p = 1; p <= i; p++)
            {
                if (lastInt == 1)
                {
                    printer("0", newLine:false);
                    lastInt = 0;
                }
                else if (lastInt == 0)
                {
                    printer("1", newLine: false);
                    lastInt = 1;
                }

            }
            printer(Environment.NewLine, WdColor.wdColorLightOrange);
        }

        doc.SaveAs2(filePath);
        doc.Close();

    }
```

I would strongly recommend reading up on how to manipulate data within Word document but this should give you a good idea on how to save what you are trying to print to console. Anything you are printing to Console with Console.WriteLine() cannot be redirected to write to word document within the c# code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of saving the output to Word files:

1. You can automate Word from any application. See [How to automate Microsoft Word to create a new document by using Visual C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-word-create-file-using-visual-c) for more information.
2. Create a Word document without Office automation involved. [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) is built on the `System.IO.Packaging` API and provides strongly-typed classes to manipulate documents that adhere to the Office Open XML File Formats specification.